# why do i get a black screen in pygame even though the surfaces seem to have been placed properly

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to Python and I'm following along on a youtube video called the ultimate introduction to Pygame. I've had everything working and I just opened the file to start adding more code and my screen no longer populates. what it should show is a sky, the ground, a little space man, and a snail that moves left to right. it seems like the surfaces are being placed because i can still interact with them on the screen and get the print statements to go, but its just black.

heres the code, I'm not sure how to even start troubleshooting this because im not getting a traceback or anything. it's technically all working.

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Runner")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
test_font = pygame.font.Font("font/pixeltype.ttf", 75)

sky_surface = pygame.image.load('graphics/sky.png').convert_alpha()
ground_surface = pygame.image.load('graphics/ground.png').convert_alpha()
score_surface = test_font.render("Runnin' Round!", False, (64, 64, 64))
score_rect = score_surface.get_rect(midtop=(400, 50))


snail_surface = pygame.image.load("graphics/snail/snail1.png").convert_alpha()
snail_rect = snail_surface.get_rect(bottomright=(600, 300))
player_surface = pygame.image.load("graphics/player/player_walk_1.png").convert_alpha()
player_rect = player_surface.get_rect(topleft=(80, 200))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        # if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        #    if player_rect.collidepoint(event.pos): print("collision") #works with black screen??

    screen.blit(sky_surface, (0, 0))  # place sky
    screen.blit(ground_surface, (0, 300))  # place ground
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, '#c0e8ec', score_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, '#c0e8ec', score_rect, 10)
    screen.blit(score_surface, score_rect)
    print('placed background') #test to see if above is broke

    snail_rect.x -= 5
    if snail_rect.right <= 0:
        snail_rect.left = 800
    screen.blit(snail_surface, snail_rect)  # place snail
    screen.blit(player_surface, player_rect)  # place player

    if player_rect.colliderect(snail_rect):
        print("colission") #also works with black screen???

    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if player_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        print(pygame.mouse.get_pressed()) #this works even with black screen????

    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

In the while true before clock.tick or after
Type`pygame.display.update()`
You are not updating the display so it is black